# Remove “ from text in php

Tags: php

I have the text :

> I like “ that cat …. But “ ….

I want to remove the `“` from the above text like this:

> I like that cat …. But  ….

I tried to use `preg_replace()` for removing `“`.But it was not working.

Comment: your error is with quotes. your are using `“` instead of `"`. so try to change editor to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `str_replace()`. Like this:

```
$quotes = array('“', '”', '‘', '’', '"', "'"); // ithink its called smart quote
$text = 'I like “ that cat …. But “ ….';
$text = str_replace($quotes, '', $text);
echo $text;

I like that cat …. But ….
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_replace() function.

```
$string= 'I like “ that cat …. But “';

$str = str_replace('"','',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'I like “ that cat …. But “';
echo str_replace('“','',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try trim() function like

```
str="I like “ that cat …. But “ ….";

echo trim($str, '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sectence = ' I like “ that cat …. But “';
str_replace('"', '', $sentence);
```

Hope this can help you.